# How can I show image in ListView element?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I want to show image after every ListView element.But of course other image any element.So, image_1.png for first ListView item,image_2.png for second ListView item etc.I guess I should do binding.How can I implement ?

```
<ListView x:Name="listView">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <!-- IMAGE IS HERE -->
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Edit (1):

I tried everything but it doesn't work.My code now:

Model class:

```
public ImageSource image { get; set; }
```

Page class:

```
BitmapImage bi = new 
bi.UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Logos/x.png");
c.image = bi;
```

XAML file:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Source=image}"></Image>
```

Why it doesn't work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I can answer my own question.I found solution

```
Image image = new Image();
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"ms-appx:/Assets/Logos/x.png"));

<Image Source="{Binding Path=image.Source.UriSource.AbsolutePath}" Width="55" Height="40"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can bind to the items in your collection like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="UI">
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=UI,Path=YourCollection}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Width="200" Height="200">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
 </Window>
```

Hypothetical class/list

```
 /// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyListItem> _yourCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyListItem>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        YourCollection.Add(new MyListItem { Title = "Item 1", Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\\Users\\Dev\\Pictures\\Picture1.PNG", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)) });
        YourCollection.Add(new MyListItem { Title = "Item 2", Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\\Users\\Dev\\Pictures\\Picture2.PNG", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)) });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyListItem> YourCollection
    {
        get { return _yourCollection; }
        set { _yourCollection = value; }
    }
}

public class MyListItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage Image { get; set; }
}
```